# Randomise multidimensional array based on a particular subarray value?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to randomise this array based on emp_score field. If emp_score value is same of multiple arrays then shuffle the array in a way that everytime it changes order of this array in a group. so the order of all the arrays with same emp_score should be different every time.

**current** **array** -

```
Array (
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 13
    [emp_name] => Joe Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/joeblock.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 27
    [emp_name] => Jon Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/jondoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 6
    [emp_name] => Jane Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/janeblock.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 22
    [emp_name] => Jane Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/janedoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 2
    [emp_name] => Scott Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/scottdoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => ACT
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 8
    [emp_name] => Brad block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/bradblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.92857142
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 20
    [emp_name] => Scott Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/scottblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.92307692
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 1
    [emp_name] => Brad doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/barddoe.png
    [emp_score] => 6.9090909
    [emp_state] => ACT
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 2
    [emp_name] => Peter Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/peterblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.875
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 4
    [emp_name] => Peter doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/peterdoe.png
    [emp_score] => 6.875
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 11
    [emp_name] => Harry Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/harryblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.85714285
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 15
    [emp_name] => James Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/jamesblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.84615384
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
)
```

**Expected** **array**-

```
Array (

    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 6
    [emp_name] => Jane Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/janeblock.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 22
    [emp_name] => Jane Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/janedoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => WA
    )

    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 27
    [emp_name] => Jon Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/jondoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 2
    [emp_name] => Scott Doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/scottdoe.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => ACT
    )

    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 13
    [emp_name] => Joe Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/joeblock.png
    [emp_score] => 7
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )

    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 8
    [emp_name] => Brad block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/bradblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.92857142
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 20
    [emp_name] => Scott Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/scottblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.92307692
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 1
    [emp_name] => Brad doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/barddoe.png
    [emp_score] => 6.9090909
    [emp_state] => ACT
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 4
    [emp_name] => Peter doe
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/peterdoe.png
    [emp_score] => 6.875
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 2
    [emp_name] => Peter Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/peterblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.875
    [emp_state] => NSW
    )
    
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 11
    [emp_name] => Harry Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/harryblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.85714285
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
    Array (
    [emp_vid] => 15
    [emp_name] => James Block
    [emp_pic] => https://www.weburl/GoldClub/jamesblock.png
    [emp_score] => 6.84615384
    [emp_state] => WA
    )
)
```

Comment: split the array into nested arrays with each `emp_score` value. Shuffle each nested array, then merge them back together.

Answer (score 0):

I created this function to help you with that. It takes the values of the emp_vid and creates an array out of it, shuffles the array, and replaces the emp_vid with the shuffled values. This randomizes the emp_vid every time.

```
function shuffleArrayValue($arr, $value) {

    $newArr=[];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $newArr[$i] = $item[$value];
        $i++;
    }
    shuffle($newArr);
    for($j=0; $j<count($newArr); $j++) {
        $arr[$j][$value] = $newArr[$j];
    }
    return $arr;

}
```

To test the function, assuming your array looks like this:

```
$empArr = array (
    array (
        'emp_vid' => 13,
        'emp_name' => 'Joe Block',
        'emp_pic' => 'https://www.weburl/joeblock.png',
        'emp_score' => 7,
        'emp_state' => 'NSW'
    ),
    array (
        'emp_vid' => 27,
        'emp_name' => 'Jon Doe',
        'emp_pic' => 'https://www.weburl/jondoe.png',
        'emp_score' => 7,
        'emp_state' => 'WA'
    ),
    array (
        'emp_vid' => 6,
        'emp_name' => 'Jane Block',
        'emp_pic' => 'https://www.weburl/janeblock.png',
        'emp_score' => 7,
        'emp_state' => 'NSW'
    ),
);

print_r(shuffleArrayValue($empArr, 'emp_vid'));
```

Enjoy!!!